# Why i am getting a wrong answer while solving this probability question.

Tags: probability

> I came across this question in a competent exam which is like
>
> P is an even number  greater than 99.
>       e is the probability of number of even numbers divisible by p,
>       o is the probability of number of odd number divisible by p and 
>       w is the probability of number of whole numbers divisible by p.

Then which of the equation satisfies the answer.

> 1  w=e
>
> 2. w=e/2
> 3. w=o/2

My Answer Approach 1

```
w=probability of(whole number/even number)
prob of((even+odd)/even)
prob of(even/even + odd/even)
e + o
now we see an odd no can never be divisible by an even no
so, prob of(odd/even)=o=zero
therefore 
w=e+zero
w=e
```

Approach 2

```
case 1 p=4 so the favorable outcomes are 4,8,12,16,20 etc
and its sample space is 1 for this.
Similarly for p=6,favorable outcomes are 6,12,18,24,30 etc and its sample space is 1.
So,in general lets say nos are Ne/pe where Ne is the all possible even numbers
 and pe is all possible even numbers to which Ne is divisible.

case 2 p=3 so the favorable outcomes are 3,9,15 etc
and its sample space is 1 for this.
Similarly for p=5,favorable outcomes are 5,15,25,35,45 etc and its sample space is 1.
So,in general lets say nos are No/po where No is the all possible odd numbers
and po is all possible odd numbers to which it is divisible.

case 3 p=1 so the favorable outcomes are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc
and its sample space is 1 for this.
So,In general lets say nos are Nw/pw where Nw is the all possible whole numbers 
and pw is all possible whole numbers to which it is divisible.

Now How to solve after this
:w=Nw/pw=(Ne+No)/(pe)=Ne
The and still came the same
```

I want to ask is "it a correct approach and Is it right"?

Comment: This is so hard to read. Take a minute and try to format it please.

Comment: @AJStas I have pasted the source from where i got this question.Will it be helpful to you as i was unable to edit how exactly you wanted

Comment: `probability of number of numbers`??? What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @barack manos: I did not have an idea to that nor i have a clue will it have any effect.I tried the question and i solved it.

Comment: Why there are negative reviews?Downvoters Please Explain rather than answering a basic question u do the opposite Does this site doesn't support trying out and following where u went wrong.Also Tell me how to edit I pasted the Source.U want me to paste the image for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is not quite correct, but your approach is on the right track.  Your flaw comes in where you obtained that $w = e + o$.  These are probabilities, so cannot be simply added as is.  Suppose you took a finite subset to start with: $N_e$ even numbers numbers and $N_o$ odd.  Then you could expect $e \cdot N_e$ of these to satisfy the condition, of the $N_o + N_e$ numbers in total.  The total probability would then be $ w = \frac{e N_e}{N_e + N_o}$.

In your case, you have infinitely many odd and even numbers to work with, but they come in equal numbers (loosely speaking).  So your probability would be 
$$w \sim \frac{e N_e + o N_o}{N_e + N_o} = \frac{e N_e + 0}{2 N_e} = \frac e2.$$

Comment: is the second approach on right track?

Comment: Why u did eNe or oNo?i have not undserstood this?